# How to generate coordinate points of a smallcircle on earth

Tags: computational-geometry

I am looking up celestial navigation, and according to
https://youtu.be/-ARXW8InStY?t=3320
a specific sun angle reading (sun angle above the horizon) will be the same on a small-circle with the centre point where the sun is at its zenith on earth.

I would like to convince myself about that using Stellarium, but I would need an Ocatve code to generate longitudes and latitudes of points of a small-circle given a radius and a centre point.

Could someone help with that, or sketch how I could progress this, sadly I know almost nothing about spherical trigonometry.

Comment: This is implemented for [Matlab](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/map/generate-small-circles.html). But I don't know whether the code is available.